# Selector doesn't respond to click event

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I've tried understanding why

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/partTime"
            style="@style/FilterFragment.JobTypeButton"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:onClick="@{(view) -> vm.updateJobType(view.getId())}"
            android:text="@string/part_time"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fullTime"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fullTime" />
```

with the style

```
<style name="FilterFragment"/>
<style name="FilterFragment.JobTypeButton" parent="TextLittleButtonWhite">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_job_type</item>
    <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/add</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

whose background is a selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_job_type_selected" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_job_type_selected" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_job_type_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_job_type_unselected" />
```

doesn't update when selected. I can't find something wrong with any of them, and if you select a button, destroy the fragment, and return to the original fragment, then the appropriate background is displayed. Why isn't the background updating when the button is selected?

Comment: Did you try it using a standard onClick function rather than a Lambada?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create

```
@BindingAdapter("selected")
fun Button.select(selected: Boolean) {
    isSelected = selected
}
```

and add it to the button like so (bottom attribute)

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/partTime"
            style="@style/FilterFragment.JobTypeButton"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:onClick="@{(view) -> vm.updateJobType(view.getId())}"
            android:text="@string/part_time"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fullTime"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fullTime"
            app:selected="@{vm.isPartTime}" />
```

The `onClick` updates `isPartTime` in my viewmodel, which is observed by `app:selected`. `vm.isPartTime` binds my viewmodel's `ObservableBoolean` to the button.